# What is the purpose of String.concat() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I know you can concatenate a string like this in Javascript:

```
str1 + str2;
```

Or like this:

```
[str1, str2].join('');
```

Why is there a function to do this, too?

```
str1.concat(str2)
```

Is it any faster? Just seems like more typing to me. My guess is that this was used before `str1 + str2` was optimized. Would that be correct?

Comment: You can pass it to a function as a parameter, which you can't do with `+` :-)

Comment: @Cameron: That is incorrect. http://jsfiddle.net/HeyJavascript/KauJS/

Comment: You're passing a string. I meant, you can't pass the `+` operator, but functions are first-class objects.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. Right. Cool. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.prototype.concat` method is very generic ([ECMA Standard 5.1 Edition / June 2011](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), pp.143-144):

> 1. Call CheckObjectCoercible passing the *this* value as its argument.
> 2. Let *S* be the result of calling *ToString*, giving it the *this* value as its argument.
> 3. Let *args* be an internal list that is a copy of the argument list passed to this function.
> 4. Let *R* be *S*.
> 5. Repeat, while *args* is not empty
>
>    a. Remove the first element from *args* and let *next* be the value of that element.
>
>    b. Let *R* be the String value consisting of the characters in the previous value of *R* followed by the 
>      characters of ToString(*next*).
> 6. Return *R*.

Because it's so generic it can be used on almost every object that has a `ToString()` method. See also the following note:

> **NOTE:**
>   The concat function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its *this* value be a String object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

So you can use `String.prototype.concat.call(myObject,....);`. Note that there's also a `Array.prototype.concat` method, which is also very generic (p. 125).

Comment: +1 for a very informative answer. This actually addressed why there's a String.concat() method, as opposed to whether it will be faster or slower.

Comment: It should be slower, since it's always calling `ToString()` and copies the argument list, while `+` only concatenates strings without creating this overhead.

Comment: `+` can be applied to Objects as well, and does exactly the same (`toString` and concatenation).

Comment: While this is true, `+` will concatenate the strings, but it isn't stated how this is done. The Addition operator is only defined as "Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)". *How* the strings are concatenated is an implementation detail.

Comment: The point is, the ability to "concatenate" objects is not the reason why `String.concat` exists. I guess the actual intent was to make JavaScript look more like Java (which has both `str+str` and `str.concat`).

Answer (score 4):

> Is it any faster?

On the contrary, it seems it can be significantly slower.

http://jsperf.com/concat-operator-vs-concat

Answer (score 2):

Appears there are significant performance differences, especially for IE:

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/09/string-performance-an-analysis/

Comment: good point, good point... The article talks about how operators on strings are as basically as optimized as they're going to get across all browsers, I'm sure that has only been improved since then.

Answer (score -1):

It's not going to be any faster or slower than the operator overload.